# Two UITableView in same Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I think this is a bug.

IOS 7.0, XCode 5.

I am having a Table View Controller in my storyboard. I have a TableView with "3" Static Cells. Then I added a "View" and inside that I added a TableView with Dynamic Prototypes.

When I try to add more than "3" cells in the Dynamic Table, the app crashes.

```
2016-01-10 08:18:21.358 Know[1381:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017535e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d68b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01707a32 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   UIKit                               0x00772983 -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] + 50
    4   UIKit                               0x00504fba -[UITableViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] + 61
    5   UIKit                               0x00333920 -[UITableView _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 349
    6   UIKit                               0x0049a8f7 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 133
    7   UIKit                               0x0049eb3d -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 98
    8   UIKit                               0x003274c2 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 120
    9   UIKit                               0x00326e6f -[UITableView reloadData] + 814
    10  UIKit                               0x0032a8d3 -[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 65
    11  UIKit                               0x0032f4f4 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 36
    12  UIKit                               0x002b3dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate)
```

This is the section count for the Static table.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (tableView == self.ismTableView) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        // Static sections
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Even though I am checking for the table name and returning proper count, it doesn't seem to take it.

Comment: And you have the table view check in every method? Why don't you use child view controllers?

Comment: @Wain Yes, check in every method. How to use child view controller? What would I specify for custom class?

Answer (score 1):

The second table view is calling the default implementation of the tableView methods, this default implementations work with the tableView property of the controller (first table view) which only has three cells. So I guess you're gonna have to override all the methods that receive the indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (tableView == self.ismTableView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        // Static sections
        return 3;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows.
    if (tableView == self.ismTableView) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        // Static sections
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 0;
}
```

Without adding `indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath`, it was throwing another exception:

```
2016-01-10 08:32:07.134 Know[1607:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017535e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d68b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01707a32 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   UIKit                               0x00772b9e -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:] + 127
    4   UIKit                               0x0050509a -[UITableViewController tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:] + 61
    5   UIKit                               0x00332035 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 1786
    6   UIKit                               0x002aaf5f +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    7   UIKit                               0x002aafa8 +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 40
    8   UIKit                               0x00331936 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 108
    9   UIKit                               0x00337d4d -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 442
    10  UIKit                               0x00337e03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    11  UIKit                               0x0031c124 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
    12  UIKit                               0x0032f5a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    13  UIKit                               0x002b3dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014e881f -[NSObject
```